# Дан массив из N натуральных чисел. Указать те числа, остаток от деления которых на М равен L (0 ≤ L ≤ M-1)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> Дан массив из N натуральных чисел. Указать те числа, остаток от
>   деления которых на М равен L (0 ≤ L ≤ M-1).

```
#include "stdafx.h"   
#include <iostream>  
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <locale.h>  

using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
    int n=15, k=0, i,m1, m, l;  
    int b[15],A[15];  
    k=0;  
    m1=0;  
    cout<<"vvedite m и l";  
    cin>>m;  
    cin>>l;  
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)   
    {  
        cout << "A[" << i << "] = ";  
        cin >> A[i];  

    }  
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)   
    {  
        l=A[i]%m;  
        if ((0<=l)&&(l<=(m-1)))  
        {  
            b[k]=i;  
            cout <<"b["<<k<<"]="<<b[k]<<endl;  
            k++;  
        }  
    }           
    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: В чём вопрос то?

Comment: Вопрос не содержит вопроса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> l=A[i]%m;  
> if ((0<=l)&&(l<=(m-1)))
> ```

```
if (A[i] % m == l)
```

Comment: А за что минус?

Comment: это не я. не могу пока

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)   
{  
    if (l == A[i]%m);  
        cout << A[i] <<endl;  
}
```

Остаток от деления на `M` всегда будет в диапазоне от `0`  до `M-1`. Кстати, наверное, имеет смысл проверить при вводе `l` и `m`, что `0 ≤ L ≤ M-1`...